# Send Email from Changes in Column Values from Appscript Google Sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I write a script to send me an email notification if there's changes in my spreadsheet based on several condition (cell value > 0 and cell value != "")
There's a flaw in this script as i use importrange and i use trigger on change. So importrange seems update its value every 2 minutes. Then trigger will fire with the same message in the mail.

What i want to do is to add if condition based on changes of the column value. If the column is changes to different value, let the script trigger send email. But if the column doesn't change, it won't trigger the script to send email. Although this condition is met ((cell value > 0 and cell value != "")).

I'd be happy to get any clue or better script come up.
Here's my script

```
    function Alert_Pos_Kerja() {
 
  var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log(" quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
  // Pulls data from the spreadsheet
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(
    "Alert_Pos Kerja"
  );
  var date = new Date();
  // Get the day of the week (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, ..., 6 for Saturday)
  var day = date.getDay();
  // Get the hour of the day (0 for midnight, 1 for 1 am, ..., 23 for 11 pm)
  var hour = date.getHours();

  //Prepares the email alert content
  let message =  "Alert Trade, Services & Investment-Retail Trade: <br><br>";
  let send_message = false;
  // Check if the day is a weekday and the hour is between 9 am and 4 pm
  if (day >= 1 && day <= 5 && hour >= 8 && hour <= 16) {
    let source = sheet.getRange("A:t");
    let data = source.getValues();





console.log("starting loop");

//Loops through the cells in the spreadsheet to find cells where the stock fell below purchase price
let n = 0;
for (let i in data) {
  //Skips the first row
  if (n++ <= 3) continue;

  //Loads the current row
  let row = data[i];

  console.log(row[1]);
  console.log(row[4]);
  console.log(row[5]);

  //Once at the end of the list, exits the loop
  if (row[4] == "") break;

  //If value is below purchase price, adds stock ticker and difference to list of tax loss opportunities
  // if(row[5]>0&&(row[6]!="" || row[6]!="Cek SOTP")){
  if(row[5]>0&& row[6]!="" ){
    message +=
      " <br>"+
      row[4] +
      ": " +
      " , Last : "+
      row[5]+
      " , Action : "+
      row[6]+
      " , Info: "+
      row[3]+
      " , Tanggal Info : " +
      row[1]+
      " , Technical : " +
      row[7]+
      " , Target Price : " +
      row[8]+
      " , Remark : " +
      row[9]+
      " , Sektor : " +
      row[10]+
      " , Risk Close : " +
      row[11]+
      " , Price & % to Upper R : " +
      row[12]+" "+row[14]*100+"%"+
      " , Price & % to Lower S : " +
      row[13]+" "+row[15]*100+"%"+
      " ,  quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining +
      " <br>";
    send_message = true;
  }
   }

  if (!send_message) return;
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    // to: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getOwner().getEmail(),
    to: '<<email>>',
    subject: "Alert Trade, Services & Investment-Retail Trade",
    htmlBody: message,
   
  });
  }
 
}
```

Here's sample for my spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LcJLqQLNXJp-B1V9Knf4l1gGZIaelZkh9VEkJ8rivTI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: there are no triggers that respond to changes caused by formula's or scripts except for onChange of type "OTHER" which I think responds to import functions.  If they allowed such triggers to exist I think it would make them very vulnerable to DDOS attacks.

Comment: @Cooper That sentence is worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no triggers that respond to changes caused by formula's or scripts except for onChange of type "OTHER" which I think responds to import functions. If they allowed such triggers to exist I think it would make them very vulnerable to DDOS attacks.